# php - call to a function on each 5 records from result set

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to use the adaptive payment api and as i know i can use it only for 5 or 6 records.
Is there a way to automate the process to fetch for example 6 records call the function on result
and then from the 6 record start the process again ?

i can't use any php database class because i'm using it in a wordpress plugin.
just for reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

example result:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [seller_paypal1] => yehuda@site.com
            [commission1] => 16.5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [seller_paypal2] => yehuda@site.com
            [commission2] => 16.5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [seller_paypal3] => yehuda@site.com
            [commission3] => 16.5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [seller_paypal4] => yehuda@site.com
            [commission4] => 16.5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [seller_paypal5] => yehuda@site.com
            [commission5] => 16.5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [seller_paypal6] => yehuda@site.com
            [commission6] => 16.5
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [seller_paypal7] => yehuda@site.com
            [commission7] => 16.5
        )

)


<?php
// just a fiction way for example
foreach ($records /5 as record) {
  start record 0-5
  adaptive($record['seller_paypal'], $record['commission']);
  //5 records finished start from the 6-11
}

function adaptive($seller_email,$commission) {
// stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PDOStatement::fetchAll` — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows or as you want

Comment: Hi, i'm using this in wordpress and all the result return as the example i posted.

Comment: $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
var_dump($result);   //are used var_dump();